# Conservation of energy, what about emitted light energy?

Tags: visible-light, energy-conservation, everyday-life, dissipation

So, this might sound rather childish, but I was walking a dark mountain road yesterday night and started thinking a bit. My phone's battery is used to light up it's torchlight, which then is used to create light that helps me see around.

Things might be a bit confusing in my head, but that torchlight emits both heat energy and light. The heat energy will somehow dissipate in the air, but the light energy will go around me to lit up the objects, reflecting said light into my eyes, but then, where is that energy? Is light energy *absorbed* by objects? I always remember the "everything is transformed, nothing is lost" when talking about energy, so what about that light that goes reflecting in the guardrail? In what it is transformed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The light from your torch bounces of different surfaces. Each time it bounces off something, it loses some of its energy and the lost energy gets converted to heat. Thus after multiple collisions, it gets almost completely "absorbed" and all its energy is dissipated as heat. Here by losing energy, I mean that the light's intensity decreases while its frequency remains the same. Since intensity depends on frequency and the number of  photons, and since the frequency stays the same, thus this is only possible when the number of photons being reflected are lesser than the number of photons incident.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Reflections don't typically turn blue into green into red into infrared. They either absorb the photon or reflect it with essentially the same frequency.

Comment: @knzhou Yes. The frequency doesn't change, however the intensity does decrease.

Comment: So it does turn into heat in the end. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Think of light as a steady flow of energy from the torch to the environment, or with a particle point of view a sea of photons flying in many directions. Some travel very far away, some hit a tree or a car or the ground and scatters in other directions. Among all these photons, some enter your eye and get absorbed by your retina cells (rod cells, cone cells) which excite electric signals in these cells. These electric signals go on to enter a network of other neurons to create a mental model of your surroundings, which is the part of consciousness your call the eyesight.

Therefore, in terms of energy, the light you "see" is but a simulation of the surrounding you created by absorbing a small fraction of the photons(each carrying some energy) that bounces off the objects around you. While the energy flow from the torch is really shooting outwards to the distance.